# File won't open, even though stat() can find it

Tags: c++, file-io, stat

I have a C++ document in which I need to open a file.  I'm not using a relative path to refer to my file.  I'm currently using the full file path on my hard drive, although later I'll switch to just using the current directory.  In any case, I know for a FACT that this file is being referred to correctly and is open-able, because I've performed stat() on the filename and it returns all of the correct info about the file.  Here's the basic process that's happening:

```
string fName = "C:\\Users\\[user]\\Downloads\\file.DAT";
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(fName);

struct _stat buf;                        // I put these lines here to test that
int result = _stat(fName.c_str(), &buf); // the file is being referred-to right

inFile >> levelnumber;
if(inFile.fail())  // inFile.fail() keeps evaluating to TRUE
    ThrowError("Corrupt or inaccesible .DAT file."); // I wrote ThrowError
```

Anyway, inFile.fail() keeps evaluating to true, even though the file is **definitely** being referred-to correctly (that's what the call to _stat() checks).

What am I doing wrong? :P

Comment: `stat` can tell you details about the file even if you don't have permission to read the contents. You might want to check out the `access` function if you are looking for that sort of behaviour.

Comment: Alternatively you can check the `st_mode` member of `buf`.

Comment: What's the declaration of `levelnumber`?  Does the data at the start of the file correctly parse as that type?

Comment: Also, you never check the result of your `_stat` call. If it is like the POSIX `stat` function then you should be checking for a result of 0 to assume success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test doesn't tell you whether the file could be opened. What your test tells you is that either the file couldn't be opened or `levelnumber` couldn't be read. To test if your file was opened, you can check the file right after the call to `open()`. If the file is indeed readable, it should convert to `true`:

```
std::ifstream inFile(fName);
if (!inFile) {
    std::cerr << "failed to open '" << fName << "' for reading\n";
}
```

Comment: OK.  That's helpful.  I think it must have been opening the file correctly but not reading the data correctly.  Turns out I should actually be using binary file I/O for what I'm doing.  I think I can take it from here...